# Posting a session array to another page

Tags: php

is it possible to post a session array from one page to another and if so how :D

regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the session alive with `session_start();`, and remember NOT to print out any content before that. Do `print_r($_SESSION);` to see what's available after you've set some session variables on a prior page.

And yes that's how they were designed by nature.

Answer (score 1):

Session variables are transferred by default if you use session_start()

Read here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 1):

By definition, that's what sessions are supposed to do. I suggest you give the following a quick read, starting from the introduction:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php